# Progress Dialog only shows up when the job is already done

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have a problem which I don't understand. I want to show a simple Progress Dialog in Android. So I created an `AsyncTask` and create the dialog in the constructor. I use the methods `onPreExceution` to `initialise` the dialog and the `onPostExecute` method I destory the dialog. So until now this looks total correct for me. But when I start the App on my Nexus 7 the dialog doesn't show up till the job is done. So it shows up for a half of a second at the end of the job... What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help ;)

```
public class ParseHTMLCodeNew extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    public ParseHTMLCodeNew(Context context) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //einrichten des Wartedialogs
        dialog.setTitle("Bitte warten!");
        dialog.setMessage("Die Kommentare werden vom Server geladen.");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String params) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String data = "";
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL( params[0] ); 
            is = url.openStream(); 
            data = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("//html//").next(); 
        } 
        catch ( Exception e ) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {       
        //Dialog beenden RSS Feed ist fertig  geparst
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }        
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is my new AsyncTask:

```
public class ParseHTMLCodeNew extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
ProgressDialog dialog;
private final OnCompleteTaskListener onCompleteTaskListener;

public interface OnCompleteTaskListener {
        void onComplete(String data);
}

public ParseHTMLCodeNew(Context context, OnCompleteTaskListener taskListener) {
    onCompleteTaskListener = taskListener;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    //einrichten des Wartedialogs
    dialog.setTitle("Bitte warten!");
    dialog.setMessage("Die Kommentare werden vom Server geladen.");
    dialog.show();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    InputStream is = null; 
    String data = "";
    try 
    { 
      URL url = new URL( params[0] ); 
      is = url.openStream(); 
      data = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("//html//").next(); 
    } 
    catch ( Exception e ) { 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    return data;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){

  onCompleteTaskListener.onComplete(result);

  //Dialog beenden RSS Feed ist fertig  geparst
  if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
      dialog.dismiss();
  }




}
}
```

And i am calling it this way:

```
new ParseHTMLCodeNew(this,new OnCompleteTaskListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(String data) {
            gData = data;

        }
    }).execute(url);
```

As i commented on your post, `data` has no value.

Comment: How long does it take for the job to complete?

Comment: show us how are you calling this code, it seem to be ok

Comment: i am calling the code this way:
data = new ParseHTMLCodeNew(CommentActivity.this).execute(url).get();

Comment: and the job needs just seconds.. sometimes 5-10 sometimes less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you calling this code so:

```
String data = new ParseHTMLCodeNew(CommentActivity.this).execute(url).get();
```

Then you do not really see your dialogue because there is a blocking UI. 
Method get() waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

Call so:

```
new ParseHTMLCodeNew(CommentActivity.this).execute(url);
```

and the result of the work is handled directly in the AsyncTask.

If you need to transfer the data to the main thread, you should tell him that the task was completed.
Wat is the simple code, I just added **OnCompleteTaskListener interface**

```
public class ParseHTMLCodeNew extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private final OnCompleteTaskListener onCompleteTaskListener;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public interface OnCompleteTaskListener {
        void onComplete(String data);
    }

    public ParseHTMLCodeNew(Context context, OnCompleteTaskListener taskListener) {
        onCompleteTaskListener = taskListener;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        // einrichten des Wartedialogs
        dialog.setTitle("Bitte warten!");
        dialog.setMessage("Die Kommentare werden vom Server geladen.");
        dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // your code here
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                sb.append(i);
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        // Dialog beenden RSS Feed ist fertig geparst
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        onCompleteTaskListener.onComplete(result);
    }
}
```

And the example of a call

```
new ParseHTMLCodeNew(this,new OnCompleteTaskListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(String data) {
                Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }).execute("your_url");
```

Be careful, this code can produce errors when you rotate your Phone. 
When Activity destroyed but task is performed:
- progress dialog will close and will not open again
- local variable to dialog or context is incorrect.

If the operation is performed for a long time can make it through the of the services?

Comment: that solves the problem with the progress dialog. Thank you! 
But i don't get any results back from the onComplete Method... data is always null... my guess is that it does not jump into the onPostExceutive Method. At least i can't see that when i am debugging

Comment: I added it to the main post

Comment: Are you sure that the block 'try/catch' is executed?

Comment: This archive with a full example,everything works
http://www.filedropper.com/sampleasyncdlg

Comment: Ahh i am a fool... i used the variable data while the asyncTask was active so data always was null.. my mistake. But Thank you very much! You helped me a lot! 
It would be nice if some admin oder user with more reputation than myself can vote your post up and mark it as correct! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote a code that get data from online database and populate that data in lisview here is the part of my code hope that help !

```
class LoadMyData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        //Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getParent());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }


        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                    //Your code here 

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting the data
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // In my case use my adapter to display the data in a listview 


                    adapter = new MyAdaper();
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Progress dialog should be shown from UI thread

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
dialog.setTitle("Bitte warten!");
dialog.setMessage("Die Kommentare werden vom Server geladen.");
dialog.show();
}});
```

Comment: I dont think that this solution is useful for me. I have to use the asyncTask either way, because of the network access...

Comment: Yes, do use asynctasks, but in your preExecute and postExecute methods, any access to dialog should run on ui thread